# Help with switching the wires from heat to AC

Tags: hvac

I can’t remember which wire to move to switch from heat to AC. I remember it was very simple, I believe just one wire. (I thought grey?) This is a old unit, but it still works good.
I’m not sure if you need more information or a different image to figure this out? I don’t really know anything about this.
Thanks[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo that shows where the individual wires exit the thermostat cable please?

Comment: Including the make/model of the furnace, AC unit and thermostat couldn't hurt, either.